# Canon MP600 scanner install

Tags: scanner, canon

I am attempting to utilize a Canon MP600 scanner on Ubuntu 20.04.  The Document Scanner application that is preinstalled on 20.04 sees the scanner but is not able to talk to it.  Searching thru the site it looks like the SANE package can talk to this scanner.  There are instructions to install SANE [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane).  I attempted to install the SANE package and have come across the following issues:

1. During the install itself:

   $ sudo apt-get install libsane-extras

   E:  unable to locate package libsane-extras
2. After installing (but without the above package), I attempted to follow the directions to test the application.  Perhaps there is some syntax I am missing?  Or perhaps this is related to the package that is missing?  Or is there some other action I should take?

   $ Applications > Graphics > XSane

   Applications:  command not found
3. I also tried running XSane and the below error shows up in the terminal.  Perhaps this error is due to the missing package?

   $ xsane

   Gtk-Message:  17:24:17.155:  Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module”

I would appreciate suggestions on how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Although xsane does not yet run.  I found that simple scanner can now talk to the scanner & scan (after running the above SANE installation, still missing libsane-extras).  Simple scanner had not originally been able to talk to the scanner, before installing the SANE package